# remove an element from my list (array) with an onclick function to target the right element

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I would like to delete a element in my array with JavaScript but at the moment, I get the last one every time because of my for statement. I tried with index, but doesn't work.

My JavaScript function:

```js
function removeItems(${index}) {
    console.log(${index}); 
}
```

My HTML:

```js
let affichage = `<article>`
for (var entry of Object.entries(localStorage)) {
    console.log(entry);
    productTitle = entry[0];
    parsedproduct = JSON.parse(entry[1]);
    productID = parsedproduct.productid;
    productCost = parsedproduct.productcost;
    productImage = parsedproduct.productimage;
    productQuantity = parsedproduct.productquantity;
    productColor = parsedproduct.productcolor;
    productTotalCost = parsedproduct.producttotalcost;
    productName = parsedproduct.productname;
    TotalCost += parsedproduct.producttotalcost;  
    TotalQuantity += parsedproduct.productquantity;

    document.getElementById('cart__items')
        affichage += `<article class="cart__item" data-id="${productID}" data-color="{product-color}">
        <div class="cart__item__img">
        <img src="${productImage}" alt="Photographie d'un canapé">
        </div>
        <div class="cart__item__content">
          <div class="cart__item__content__description">
            <h2>${productName}</h2>
            <p>${productColor}</p>
            <p>${productCost} €</p>
          </div>
          <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
            <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
              <p>Qté : ${productQuantity}</p>
              <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="${productQuantity}">
            </div>
            <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
              <p id="delete" class="${productTitle}" onclick="removeItems(${index})">Supprimer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>`;
        affichage += '</article>';
        document.querySelector("#cart__items").innerHTML = affichage;
    }
```

Comment: `${index}` <- this function param doesn't seem valid JavaScript.

Comment: `<p id="delete" class="${productTitle}" onclick="removeItems(${index})">Supprimer</p>` where does the index come from?
Most likely it's `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element itself, you dont need the index.

```
<html> 
onclick="removeItems(this)";
</html>

<js>
function removeItems(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
</js>
```